# ONLY keyword - meaning

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this simple case of query:

```
;WITH TEST_CTE AS
(
    SELECT 1 N

    UNION ALL

    SELECT N + 1 
    FROM TEST_CTE
    WHERE N < 50
)
SELECT N FROM TEST_CTE 
ORDER BY N
OFFSET 10 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

What does keyword `ONLY` mean here:

> FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS **ONLY**

Why is it necessary to have it there?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this - but keyword only is just used there. No word about it. Is anywhere explanation about this keyword solely?

Comment: "Why is it necessary to have it there?" because that's what the authors of T-SQL decided. Why did they decide this? I don't know.

Comment: We can say like it's part of sql syntax for FETCH NEXT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we check the [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#syntax) of the `ORDER BY` clause when `OFFSET` is used:

```
<offset_fetch> ::=  
{   
    OFFSET { integer_constant | offset_row_count_expression } { ROW | ROWS }  
    [  
      FETCH { FIRST | NEXT } {integer_constant | fetch_row_count_expression } { ROW | ROWS } ONLY  
    ]  
}
```

You can see that if you need only to `OFSET` rows, you do not need to specify how many rows to `FETCH` (you are getting all of the rest). But if you want to get particular amount of rows, the `ONLY` keyword is a must.

I try to find where exactly in the `SQL standard` this is defined, because in many cases this is just the standard - it may look as something that is not needed, but this is the standard and people are trying to follow it. So, from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)#Result_limits):

> Since ISO SQL:2008 results limits can be specified as in the following
>   example using the FETCH FIRST clause.
>
> SELECT * FROM T FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
>
> This clause currently is supported by CA DATACOM/DB 11, IBM DB2, SAP
>   SQL Anywhere, PostgreSQL, EffiProz, H2, HSQLDB version 2.0, Oracle 12c
>   and Mimer SQL.
>
> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and higher supports FETCH FIRST, but it is
>   considered part of the ORDER BY clause. The ORDER BY, OFFSET, and
>   FETCH FIRST clauses are all required for this usage.
>
> SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY acolumn DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 10
>   ROWS ONLY

You can see, that the `ONLY` keyword seems to be part of the standard definition. Below is a table where some implemented a syntax not following the standard:

[image]

So, in case of `SQL Server` the `only` keyword is a must when you are using `ORDER BY` and `FETCH`. This seems to be following the standard, so do not waste too much time to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

The `OFFSET FETCH` is used for pagination purpose ie; to retrieve only some rows as specified

```
 SELECT N FROM TEST_CTE 
 ORDER BY N
 OFFSET 10 ROWS 
 FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

So here it won't return the first 10 rows when ordering by n because it is specified as the offset . Then it will return the remaining 5 rows only

`ONLY` is used to specify the rows needed. 
If it is not specified then the query will skip the first 10 rows from the sorted result set and return the remaining rows.

If you only want to offset the rows the use `OFFSET` keyword only.
If you need to limit the number of rows returned then use `FETCH` with `ONLY`

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=984807687bf027b1eeca2ecae04ba46b)

Comment: Thanks - but is keyword ONLY described in detail anywhere? Just this keyword? Or is it simply part of offset - fetch? If you miss this keyword, there's syntax error. So it must be specified.

Comment: @FrenkyB i have updated the answer and included a demo for you.  `ONLY` is a part of fetch but not part offset.